# How to load models without related objects?

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I fetch a list of model objects from a repository object, with usual code like this:

```
...
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setStoragePageIds($projectStoragePids);
...
$query->matching($query->logicalOr($constraints));
$result = $query->execute();
```

Now if I debug the objects, I see that all the related complex objects member also have been loaded, and their related ones too and so on. So the repository is delivering a huge tree, while I just need the very list of the objects with no depth. Complex object members could be just `NULL`. Therefore building the list is too slow and unnecessary.

I am aware of `@lazy`, however it does not change if I set this attribute in the model (and clear the cache).

What options are there to disable loading related objects in depth besides `@lazy`? What automatism causes TYPO3 Domain handler to load or skip related objects?

In C#, you can choose by `.include()`. What about TYPO3?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing is that you can use `$query->statement($sql, $params)`.

It is amongst the extbased query methods:
http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-query-methods/

If you use this, you can write a `select` statement that includes only a selection of fields. The T3 model object builder will take the rows and fields you have selected, and will create model objects from the information available.

So for instance, assume we write first:

```
...
$query = $this->createQuery();  
$result = $query->execute();
return $result;
```

Like this you will get a list of objects with each object member field also initialized with an complete object.

But if we write for instance:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->statement('select uid from tx_my_table'); // <<<<<<<<  
$result = $query->execute();
return $result;
```

Then you will still get a list of objects, *but the only member field that has a real value is `uid`*. Like this, you can also select a field that points to some m:m relationship. It will be handled.

This may bring a huge gain of speed.

The caveat is that the T3 extbase repository somehow, slightly creates a mixture between your pure sql and some internal specifications. I figure some more hints might be found by the search 'TYPO3 convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder'. Further, you must rewrite your own query restrictions that are usually given by the `$querySettings`. But hey, it's an open door to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$query->execute(1);`. This is the rawResult flag which returns raw-database row as an array instead of an object. Relationships to other objects are not resolved either.